# North American housing and real-estate appraisal data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, real-estate, north-america

I am trying to perform spatial analysis regarding affordable housing across North American cities.

Does anyone know of a source (city, commercial, or other website) which offers real estate or housing appraisal data?

Comment: Assuming your are using the information for **non-commercial purposes only**, you might want to consider learning how to scrape data from Kijiji, craigslist, or other real-estate/housing websites using Python. Guides for using tools like "Scrapy" for this type of data collection are bountiful for this type of research.

Comment: What do you mean by "affordable housing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Affordable housing is difficult to track as there are intricacies to the process: Is it Housing Choice Voucher Program (Previously Section 8), is it a an established property that specifically handles affordable housing (which the government pays a private enterprise to operate), or is it public housing.

You should look at property appraiser data for each county to figure out what basic values are available, then identify where the affordable housing locations are.

Statewide Parcel Data in Shapefile Formats with Property Appraiser Data:

- Alabama: [Site with County List](http://gis.alabama.gov/Browse.aspx)
- Alaska: [Site with Borough List](http://www.asgdc.state.ak.us//#2906)
- California: [Entire State, scroll down to parcel_data.zip](ftp://data.scag.ca.gov/)
- Florida: [FTP Link for 2012 Parcel Data;](ftp://ftp.fgdl.org/pub/state/parcels_2012.zip) newer would at county level
- Montana Cadastral: [Site](http://svc.mt.gov/msl/mtcadastral/) / [FTP link for Parcel Data](ftp://ftp.geoinfo.msl.mt.gov/Data/Spatial/MSDI/Cadastral/)
- New York: [Parcels available for state and county](http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=1300)
- Utah: [County Level](https://gis.utah.gov/data/sgid-cadastre/parcels/)

Use Trevor's answer for non-commercial purposes only, [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/), is your scraping buddy.

If you adhere to the guidelines, you can access MLS data through the [Zillow API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm).

Finally, you are going to need to go the [HUD website](http://www.hud.gov/apps/section8/index.cfm) to identify affordable housing locations.